# Я не могу просто изменить цвет текста через javascript

Tags: javascript

я не могу просто изменить какое-либо значение любого объекта  через js у меня не получается я не понимаю что я делаю не так , я не могу просо цвет текста изменить почему?! объясните как это делать с любыми объектами пожалуйста

```
var cvet = document.getElementsByClassName('moz');
cvet.style.Color = 'red';
```

вот html объект , значение которого я пытаюсь изменить

```
<h1 class="moz">Mozilla is cool</h1>
```

Comment: а если так `cvet.style.Color -> cvet[0].style.color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше используй querySelector('один элемент по селектору') или querySelectorAll('массив элементов по селектору') и забудь про остальные

напоследок между ними все же есть разница... оставлю на самообучение

Comment: _"... getElementByClassName который возвращает один элемент по классу..."_  Это в каком языке программирования? Также `getElementsByClassName()` и `querySelectorAll()` возвращают коллекции, а не массивы. _"... лучше используй...  и забудь про остальные"_ Каждый метод для своей задачи, и нет лучше или хуже. "Живая" коллекция - это не то же самое, что статическая.

Comment: @UModel ну вот )) я сам их не использую как то не заметил что нету единичного селектора))))))))))))))) спасибо за замечание)

Comment: @UModeL а если по сушеству сколько случеев было у вас когда вы не могли использовать query... и прибегли к get...? приблизительно в процентах?)

Comment: были такие случаи. Не скажу, что много. Однажды оптимизировал чужой код, и именно "живая" коллекция из  `getElementsByClassName()` сильно так подсократила количество кода.

Comment: @Armen , спасибо . Хотел еще спросить: а могу ли я обращаться к одиночному объекту просто по классу ?И еще , хочу узнать : вот когда переменная = querySelector('p например') то эта переменная берет себе значение первого селектора в html коде или как ? Как это происходит?

Comment: @SLARDAr15 1.можно... elem.querySelector('.classname')2.да первое

Comment: @Armen , Спасибо)